# 'Enter' is not recognised during pdf conversion in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, pdf-generation, itext

I have a HTMLEditor(ajax control). i am converting the contents present in HTMLEditor into pdf as follows

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

        //Extract data from Page (pd).
        //Label16.Text = Editor1.Content; // Attribute
        // makae ready HttpContext
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        // Create PDF document
        Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);


        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream("d://" + HiddenField1.Value + HiddenField4.Value + dbDate + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDocument.Open();
        string htmlText = Editor1.Content;
        System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList (new StringReader(htmlText), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        pdfDocument.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

Now the problem is if i press enter in HTMLEditor, the generated pdf does not show any change .

I have already hardcoded some contents into HTMLEditor:

```
"<br/>" + "<P align= 'right'>"+"By Order of the Court,".Replace(Environment.NewLine,"<br/>")+"</P>" +
   "<br/><br/>" + "<P align= 'right'>( G. M. Redker )&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
   "<br/>" + "Assistant Registrar &nbsp;" +
   "<br/>" + "High Court of Bombay" +
   "<br/>" + "Panaji Bench (Goa)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + "</P>";
```

now if i press enter before By Order of the Court the changes are not transferred to pdf file.

i.e if i press enter key after a line,than pdf does not show any gap between two lines it displays a continuous line.

**All this happens only when i deploy application on server,my development machine shows a proper output.**

Is this error because i am doing the followin:

```
    string htmlText = Editor1.Content;
    System.Collections.Generic.List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList (new StringReader(htmlText), null);
    for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
    {
        pdfDocument.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
    }
```

Please help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, whitespace is collapsed in html, so this behavior seems normal. Use a <br/> tag to simulate a new line, or use <p></p> tags.

Comment: How can i use it in my code, HTMLEditor contents are modified by the user so user can press a enter key anywhere, how do i detect it?

Comment: How does your raw HTML look like after an enter? Does it insert whitespace or a br tag?

Comment: So that's the problem. Is it a WYSIWYG editor? If so, what happens if you press enter twice? If not, can you type <br/> literally?

Comment: Its a HTMLEditor(ajax control) and if i type &nbsp ; literally than pdf actually shows &nbsp ;